# User-input file path

Tags: c++, string, file-io

The program is supposed to open a text file whose path is user-input. Next, it counts the lines contained in the file and outputs them. Here's what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string path = NULL;
string garbage = NULL;
int cnt = 0;
cout << "Enter file path: ";
cin >> path;

ifstream inFile(path.c_str());
if (inFile)
{
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        getline(inFile, garbage);
        ++cnt;
    }
}
inFile.close();

cout << endl;

cout << path << " has " << cnt << " lines";


cin.ignore();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

This is what I get:

Program: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP120D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstring
Line: 1168
Expression: invalid null pointer

Note: The course I'm following has only shown me the basics of the methods used by ifstream and ofstream, like open, close and eof. So I would appreciate a solution with only these, as I'm sure you know many ways of doing this.

Comment: Your code has another (common) bug: end of file detection happens when you try to read something but you can't because you're at end of file. But you check for end of file *before* reading the line, rather than *after* reading the line, so you'll get the wrong answer.

Comment: You should use `while (getline(inFile, garbage))`

Comment: Ok, now I understand what Hurkyl was telling me. Thanks Neil.

Comment: Oh, one last comment: you should test your program with an input file whose last character is a newline and with another input file whose last character is not a newline. (and you'll also have to decide what the right answers should be in both cases)

Answer (score 1):

The class `std::string` is a reasonable container class, like `std::vector` but with an API that has a number of extra string-oriented functions.

In a particular, its use does *not* resemble old-fashioned C-style string handling in terms of `char*`, which is where I assume you got the idea of trying to use `NULL` as an initializer. (in modern C++ you should use the C++ keyword `nullptr` to create a null pointer, rather than the old C style macro `NULL`)

what `string path = NULL;` *actually* does is interpret `NULL` as a `const char*`, and then tries to read the C-style string at the location `NULL` points to so as to copy it into `path`. Since `NULL` is null rather than actually pointing to a string, you get the error message you cite.

What you really want to do is to simply use the default constructor via `string path;` which initializes `path` to be an empty string.

Comment: Can't believe it was as easy as that. However, I still don't understand what you mean about the eof bug. It outputs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the meaningless `NULL` they're not pointers:

```
string path;
string garbage;
```

Comment: I thought it was a good habit of initializing every variable you declare.

Comment: @hornet: Paul's code *does* initializer `path` and `garbage`; the default initializer for the `std::string` class creates an empty string.